# Rational Team Concert (RTC) to Subversion (SVN)

Tags: svn, migrate, rtc, rational-team-concert

How might I migrate data from RTC 4.0.2 to SVN Edge 4.0? I have a multiple vobs (total size 10 GB). I do not want to lose any data during the migration.

Please provide details on how I might perform this migration?

Comment: why do you want to move away from RTC?

Comment: Because RTC is very expensive for my company

Comment: why dont you try create project on jazzhub (http://hub.jazz.net)?

Comment: Thanks Kiran, but my company wants to use SVN

Answer (score 3):

RTC is not just a source control referential like [SVN Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion/capabilities).
you will loose during the migration any link between change sets and Work Items or Build Records, as well as the Plans and Reports.

The size of the Vobs (actually called "jazz repository", since Vob is a ClearCase term) isn't important, since you would export component per component.

Finally, I am not aware of any export tools from RTC to another VCS (and [I am not the only one](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/103877/exporting-from-jazz-source-control-to-subversion-git)).
You might need to script it in order to list and load each change set of a component, one by one, and for each change sets loaded in your local workspace, commit that content in your Subversion repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple things to add to the first answer:

- If the data migration ends up being difficult, it is very easy to write a script that brings over key milestones of history and preserves the important branching relationships.  That often ends up being much faster and easier than trying to faithfully reproduce each commit.
- Once you identify your new issue system (something like JIRA), you can try to write a script that identifies RTC links between commits and issues and reproduce them in JIRA.  That could be a non-trivial effort though.